# Update from first empty row of specific column in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table like this:

[image]

All data are random, an email or phone can belong to any name, address,...

Now I have a few more emails that I will add too. Beside using PHP `explode` and `for` loop to update to email column, I am still wondering how to query the first empty row in email column to start with.

Appreciate any helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am still wondering how to query the first empty row in email column

You seem to be looking for the lowest row id where the email is null : that’s a simple `SELECT` statement on rows having an empty email, with an `ORDER BY` to sort the results by `id` and a `LIMIT` clause to retain only the first result.

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE email IS NULL
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1
```

You can combine criterias in the `WHERE` clause with `AND`s and `OR`s to refine the search. To display all results instead of just the first, remove the `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

If:

- By "empty" you mean a row with null values,
- and by "first" you mean the row with the lowest `id` value.

Then, I would do:

```
select min(id)
from my_table
where name is null
  and address is null
  and email is null
  and phone is null
```

Comment: nice idea to get lowest ID of null values. I can choose a specific column by removing others after WHERE. Nice works!

Answer (score 1):

If "the first" translates to "with the lowest ID" you can use a subquery, that checks if there's a lower ID with an empty e-mail.

```
SELECT *
       FROM elbat t1
       WHERE t1.email IS NULL
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM elbat t2
                                    WHERE t2.id < t1.id
                                          AND t2.email IS NULL);
```

(Change `IS NULL` to `= ''` if by "empty" you mean an empty string, not null.)

But if all these values are unrelated, you should fix that design and have four independent tables. One for name, one for addresses, one for e-mails and one for phone numbers. And you shouldn't store empty values if they have no meaning in them. That way you could just do an `INSERT` and won't need to find an empty row.

Comment: another awesome idea. I will try to separate them to independent tables. Thanks